# Button clicked right when it starts?

Tags: java, button, applet

I imported an image into an applet and attempted to make it if the mouse is pressed on the button then it will return "startButtonClicked" to be true and the page will change. My problem is that as soon as i start the applet up it immediately flips to page 2 as if it was true. If i take off the line of code that changes the page if it is true away then it will go back to normal. I tested if i got the dimensions and coordinates right by drawing an oval and seeing where it would draw and it was drawn perfectly onto the button! I don't see what i'm doing wrong. (everything is implemented right)

Here is some of the code that involves it:

```
int roomPage = 0;
int xPos;
int yPos;
boolean startButtonClicked = false;
boolean instructionsButtonClicked = false;
int startButtonX = 700;
int startButtonY = 200;
```

code that involves it:

```
public void init() {
    setSize(1024,640);
    addKeyListener(this);   
    addMouseListener(this);
}

public void start(){

    if(startButtonClicked = true){
        roomPage = 2;
    }
}
```

Pages:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){      
    switch (roomPage){
    case 0: homeScreen(g); break;
    case 1: instructionsPage(g); break;
    case 2: startPage(g); break;
    }
}
```

when mouse is released:

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    xPos = me.getX(); 
    yPos = me.getY();

    if (xPos > startButtonX && xPos < startButtonX+216 && yPos >startButtonY &&  
            yPos < startButtonY+85){
        startButtonClicked = true;
    }
    else{
        startButtonClicked = false;
    }
    repaint();


}
```

i don't get any errors starting it up but it directly goes to page 2 when i start it up. :( help?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(startButtonClicked = true){
    roomPage = 2;
}
```

you are assigning startButtonClicked to true(which is always true) instead of  a conditional statement ==.

```
    if(startButtonClicked == true){
    roomPage = 2;
}
```

or

```
   if(startButtonClicked){
    roomPage = 2;
}
```

Comment: Now when i changed it to that the roomPage won't change :/

Comment: because the start() function appears to only  be called at the start of your program; you need to call this function after setting the click to true or just change the room number after setting it to true.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to:

```
if(startButtonClicked){
roomPage = 2;
}
```

it is back to normal again but when i click the button it wont change the roomPage.